# Error associated with "EXPR must be a length 1 vector" when extracting fixed effect coefficients

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, coefficients, expr

I am running a random effects mediation analysis using `lme4::lmer` and the model converged. However, when using

```
FEmatrix <- coef(medmodelsummary)
```

to extract the fixed effects, I got the following error message:

```
Error in switch(chain, 1 = -10, 2 = 10) : 
EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

I am not sure what this means and can anyone give me a hint on this?

thank you.

Comment: `methods(class="merMod")` shows a `coef` method, can you post the code used to produce the object `medmodelsummary`? Is it the output of `summary(lmer_fit)`, where `lmer_fit` has the obvious meaning?

Answer (score 0):

How about `fixef()`?
For example: https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/fixef.html

```
library(lme4)    
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + Days2 + (1|Subject),
                data=transform(sleepstudy,Days2=Days))
```

`fixef(fm2,add.dropped=TRUE)`